# Instantiate divs to a random space within a container

Tags: javascript, html, velocity.js

I know this is probably a very basic question but here goes:

I'm instantiating a number of DOM elements onto an HTML page using JS.

```
for(var i = 0; i < dotsCount; i++){
    dotsHtml += "<div class = 'dot'></div>";
}
$dots = $(dotsHtml);
$count.html(dotsHtml);
```

I want them to be spawned at randomly spaced distances but currently they're all spawning in a vertical line as you would expect.

I'm using velocity.js to animate them but I don't know how to randomise their initial position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way could be to generate a random number using [Math.random()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_random.asp), and then add in the `<div class='dot'>` a `style="margin-right:"+yourRandomNumberHere+"px"`

Comment: Thank you! I was just wondering if I would need to do it by modifying the CSS but this works for me.

Comment: If this solution is ok for you, consider to accept it!